# Create various SharePoint groups with group owner in SharePoint Online CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365

I have the script below to create a SharePoint Group in a SharePoint Online site using CSOM.

Is there a way to change it in order to create various groups instead of only one and to specify the group owner for each group?

```
$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread" #Definition of the function that allows to create a SharePoint Group in a SharePoint Online Site function 

Create-SPOGroup { 
param($sSiteColUrl,$sUsername,$sPassword,$sGroupToCreate,$sGroupToCreateDescription) 
try { 
Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------" -foregroundcolor Green 
Write-Host "Creating SharePoint Group $sGroupToCreate in $sSiteColUrl" -foregroundcolor Green 
Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------" -foregroundcolor Green 

#Adding the Client OM Assemblies 
Add-Type -Path "C:\CSOMDLL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\CSOMDLL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 

#SPO Client Object Model Context 
$spoCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($sSiteColUrl) 
$spoCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($sUsername, $sPassword) 
$spoCtx.Credentials = $spoCredentials 

#Root Web Site 
$spoRootWebSite = $spoCtx.Web 

#Object for creating a new SPO Group 
$spoGroupCreationInfo= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.GroupCreationInformation 
$spoGroupCreationInfo.Title=$sGroupToCreate 
$spoGroup=$spoRootWebSite.SiteGroups.Add($spoGroupCreationInfo) 
$spoCtx.ExecuteQuery() 

Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------" -foregroundcolor Green 
Write-Host "SharePoint Group $sGroupToCreate in $sSiteColUrl created succesfully!!" -foregroundcolor Green 
Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------" -foregroundcolor Green 
$spoCtx.Dispose() 
} 
catch [System.Exception] { 
   write-host -f red $_.Exception.ToString() 
} 
} 
#Required Parameters 
$sSiteColUrl = "test" 
$sUsername = "testuser" 
#$sPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "password" -AsSecureString 
$sPassword=convertto-securestring "password" -asplaintext -force 
$sGroupToCreate="CustomSPOGroup" 
Create-SPOGroup -sSiteColUrl $sSiteColUrl -sUsername $sUsername -sPassword $sPassword -sGroupToCreate $sGroupToCreate
```

Answer (score 2):

I am a big fan of using the PnP-PowerShell cmdlets for jobs like this: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/readme.md

You can use New-PnPGroup to create a new group, assigning all the same values you get in the GUI. You can then pipe this to Set-PnPGroupPermissions to assign rights to a particular site.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteurl -Credentials $creds
$newGroup = New-PnPGroup -Title $GroupTitle -Owner $OwnerEmail -Description $GroupDescription
Set-PnPGroupPermissions -Identity $newGroup -AddRole $AddRole
Disconnect-PnpOnline
```

You could then feed it a file with group names, permissions and sites to apply the group to, and use foreach to cycle through them.

EDIT with full script (untested)

Install instructions are here: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/README.md

Install the cmdlets, then create a .csv file with the information you want, like this.

```
siteurl,grouptitle,owneremail,groupdescription,addrole
https://tenancy.sharepoint.com/sites/site1,testgroup1,owner@tenancy.com,"This is a group description",Contribute
https://tenancy.sharepoint.com/sites/site2,testgroup2,owner2@tenancy.com,"This is another group",Read
```

Then run the following

```
$groups = import-csv "c:\pathtocsv\csvname.csv"
$creds = Get-Credential
foreach ($group in $groups){
    # Set up variables
    $siteurl = $group.siteurl
    $GroupTitle = $group.grouptitle
    $OwnerEmail = $group.owneremail
    $GroupDescription = $group.groupdescription
    $addrole = $group.addrole

    # Connect to site
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteurl -Credentials $creds
    #Create Group
    $newGroup = New-PnPGroup -Title $GroupTitle -Owner $OwnerEmail -Description $GroupDescription
    # Set Permissions on group
    Set-PnPGroupPermissions -Identity $newGroup -AddRole $AddRole
    # Disconnect from site
    Disconnect-PnpOnline
}
```

Comment: I cannot make it work... is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What issues are you having? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: The thing is that I don't know how to do it.. never worked with pnp before

Comment: Could you please help?

Comment: @PeterSmp answer updated, hope this helps